# AUTH TLS/SSL with ftp_connect function

Tags: php, ssl, ftp, ftps

According to [RFC 2228](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2228) the `AUTH` is an FTP command which can be used with one of an authentication mechanism (`TLS` or `SSL`), in order to secure both data channel and control channel.

I'm wondering if I can use this command with a non-secure connection (regular FTP) with [`ftp_connect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php) function, like this :

```php
$conn = ftp_connect('hostname');

if (is_ressoure($conn)) {
    $command = ftp_raw($conn, 'AUTH TLS');
    $responseCode = (int) substr($command[0], 0, 3);

    if ($responseCode === 234) {
        // AUTH TLS success
        login(); // secured

    } else { // if TLS rejected try SSL

        $command = ftp_raw($conn, 'AUTH SSL');
        $responseCode = (int) substr($command[0], 0, 3);

        if ($responseCode === 234) {
            // SSL authentication success
            login(); // secured

        } else {
            // Cannot secure the data channel and command channel
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the `AUTH` command used with an explicit FTP/SSL connection with [`ftp_ssl_connect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php), I'm confused and I want to know if this command is useless with a regular FTP connection?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AUTH TLS`/`SSL` turns the connection into encrypted. If you use it with a plain  `ftp_connect` connection, the connection will stop working. The server will expect encrypted commands (and will send encrypted responses) and the client (PHP FTP module) will keep sending unencrypted commands (and will expect unencrypted responses). They won't understand each other. Actually it will never even get to that, as after responding to `AUTH`, the server will initiate TLS handshake and that will fail straight away.

Comment: Actually, when a send the AUTH command with the plain mode, the server responds with a success response code, and the connection not stoped, can you please explain to me why?

Comment: That's correct. The response to `AUTH` is the last plain-text communication. But any further communication should fail.